# Use same logic for client and server side validations

Tags: java, validation, angularjs, grails, ember.js

I have an application written on Grails. I have some validation rules on server side, for instance.

```
if(fieldB.value > fieldC.value) {
    setMandatory(fieldA);
}
......
```

I don't want to repeat validation logic on client side too, because of complexity. My question is: how can I use the same logic in client side and is there any technology with the help of which I can implement this concept ?

p.s. I'm not familiar with MVC frameworks like `angularjs`, `emberjs`. Is it possible to do this with mentioned frameworks ?

Comment: Unless your server-side code is also javascript (eg, node.js or something), I don't think there's a good general solution to avoid validation duplication. One thing you could try is to separate out "helps the user" validation and "will break your code if not caught" validation -- do the former client-side and the latter server-side (and maybe also client-side).

Comment: For info: I'm using groovy and java for server side validation.

Comment: You can use Ajax (for example with jQuery) to invoke server side validation from the client

Comment: Neither Angular nor Ember are client side validation frameworks, they solve a completely different problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-validation-ui) for Grails.  Probably the best option without writing something from scratch yourself.